# Laravel Sail Set MySQL Data Configuration Setting

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel Sail with MySQL.  We have triggers on our database and I need to be able to set `log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1` in the configuration.  For the life of me, I can't figure out set this automatically when the container is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [volume in docker-compose](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/mariadb.stub#L13) to replace the config. Then it will use your new config. To copy the current config from the container to your host OS you can use `docker cp <container>:<file> <destination>`.